# Use and dipose of a Bitmap (in the near future)

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I have a problem with use this part of code.

I get 2 different exceptions:
1 - (image) - the parameter is invalid
2 - in this line: `Application.Run(new Form1());` - the parameter is not valid

I going to:

1. Create a Bitmap from a file
2. Set the Image of my PictureBox to this Bitmap
3. `.Dispose()` of the Bitmap (I want delete this file later)

---

```
Image image;
private void buttonWyswietl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(@"image.jpg"))
    {
        using (Bitmap ExampleImgBitmap = new Bitmap(@"image.jpg"))
        {
            int x, y;

            // Loop through the images pixels to reset color.
            for (x = 0; x < ExampleImgBitmap.Width; x++)
            {
                for (y = 0; y < ExampleImgBitmap.Height; y++)
                {
                    Color pixelColor = ExampleImgBitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                    Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.A, pixelColor.R, pixelColor.G, pixelColor.B);
                    ExampleImgBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
                }
            }
            // Set the PictureBox to display the image.
            image = ExampleImgBitmap;
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = image;
    }
}

private void buttonUsun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists("image.jpg")) {
        File.Delete("image.jpg");
    }
}
```

PS: I use bitmap to use gif file

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about what your problem is. Are you receiving any errors? Is it having unintended results? Please specify.

Comment: `using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"image.jpg")))) { ... pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose(); pictureBox1.Image = bitmap; }` -- Provide the full path of the Image. No need to check whether `File.Exists()`, since `File.Delete()` doesn't throw when the file is not there. It does throw if the Directory is not found. One of the reasons why you always provide the full path. -- I assume `SetPixel()` is an example: you're doing nothing right now.

Comment: If you have and exception in Program.cs (`Application.Run()`), it's probably bounced back from the Form Constructor (which you're not showing here).

Comment: You can't displose of things still needed and the Image property of a Pbox is just that: Needed until you set it to null or a different image.

Comment: Bitmap ExampleImgBitmap;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        private void buttonWyswietl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();

            if (File.Exists(@"image.jpg"))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"image.jpg", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    fs.CopyTo(ms);
                }
                ExampleImgBitmap = new Bitmap(ms, true);
                pictureBox1.Image = ExampleImgBitmap;
            }
        }

Comment: private void buttonUsun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            ExampleImgBitmap.Dispose();
            File.Delete("image.jpg");
        }

Answer (score 0):

A `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox` can't display Disposed images.
So don't dispose the image until you are certain that you don't need to display it anymore.

And another tip: to improve reusability of your code, don't do too much in one procedure.

Note: while the Image from the file is not disposed, the file is in use

```
private void buttonWyswietl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ShowImage(@"image.jpg");
}

private void ShowImage(string imageFilename)
{
    if (File.Exists(imageFileName))
    {
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"image.jpg");
        this.pictureBox1.Image = this.ChangeImage(image);
    }
    // else: TODO: what if image doesn't exist?
}

Bitmap ChangeImage(Bitmap originalImage)
{
    // Loop through the images pixels to reset color.
    for (int x = 0; x < originalImage.Width; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < exampleImgBitmap.Height; ++y)
        {
                ...
        }
    }
    return originalImage;
}
```

Now if you want to make slight changes, for instance do something similar if a menu item is clicked, or if the file name in a text box has been changed, you can reuse the images.

Or if you don't want to show the original image, but show a copy, only small change is needed.

Make sure that the image is not shown before you Dispose. Make sure the the image is Disposed before you delete the file.